# Changes done in rich datatable in included xhtml not available in bean taken from Session

Tags: html, jsf-2, richfaces

I am facing an issue where i have included an  xhtml in my page using ui:include tag. Included xhtml has a richdatatable whose value are populated from a list from Bean B. Now user can edit those value from screen. The save button and method is present on parent screen and  Bean A. I am trying to get updated values of Bean B in Bean A  using FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSessionMap().get("B").

But it has original values and not updated values and hence updates are not getting submitted.

I cannot put Save method in Bean B, since it is an existing implementation and i can't change that.

I need to find a way of saving values from a method present in Bean A.

P.S: I am getting updated values if i exclusively fire a4j:ajax event on change of any field and set it in the list. But this is not a feasible solution as my datatable has 50 rows with a vertical scroller. So if user updates 49th row, after ajax event fields are re rendered a

Comment: Did you try to inject Bean A in B like this @ManagedProperty(value="#{beanA}") 
BeanA beanA; Then add method in bean B to call method in bean A

Comment: It'll depend on the point at which you're accessing bean B and its scope; if the value binding between the page and the bean is done properly, and you're retrieving it at the right point, you shouldn't have a problem. Post the xhtml snippet here, and also your value retrieval code

Comment: @user3489875 I want to access Bean B in Bean A as my Save method is present in Bean A.

Comment: I have gone with using a4j:ajax method to populate the values. Solved rerendering problem using limitRender attribute.